# AndroidViewClient Down, Move, and Up Events

Tags: automated-tests, androidviewclient

I have managed to install, and successfully run Culebra. I previously used MonkeyRunner to move things around on the device.

```
TOUCH|{'x':106,'y':1647,'type':'down',}
WAIT|{'seconds':2.0,}
TOUCH|{'x':210,'y':1647,'type':'move',}
...
TOUCH|{'x':210,'y':1647,'type':'up',}
```

I have been looking to move the script to AndroidViewClient, but can not find anything equivalent. I know about the touch, long touch, and drag. I have seen that **adbclient** supports **DOWN**, **UP** and **DOWN_AND_UP**, but no **MOVE**.

Have I missed something? Could someone please show me where I can find some documentation on this.

Thanks,
Eugene

Answer (score -1):

In developer options enable pointer location and you can view x and y pointers. Then you can use  `device.touch(x_position,y_position)`

**eg:-**

```
~ device.touch(550,920)

0 --> "KEYCODE_UNKNOWN
1 --> "KEYCODE_MENU
2 --> "KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT
3 --> "KEYCODE_HOME
4 --> "KEYCODE_BACK
5 --> "KEYCODE_CALL
6 --> "KEYCODE_ENDCALL
7 --> "KEYCODE_0
8 --> "KEYCODE_1
9 --> "KEYCODE_2
10 --> "KEYCODE_3
11 --> "KEYCODE_4
12 --> "KEYCODE_5
13 --> "KEYCODE_6
14 --> "KEYCODE_7
15 --> "KEYCODE_8
16 --> "KEYCODE_9
17 --> "KEYCODE_STAR
18 --> "KEYCODE_POUND
19 --> "KEYCODE_DPAD_UP
20 --> "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
21 --> "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT
22 --> "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT
23 --> "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER
24 --> "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
25 --> "KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
26 --> "KEYCODE_POWER
27 --> "KEYCODE_CAMERA
28 --> "KEYCODE_CLEAR
29 --> "KEYCODE_A
30 --> "KEYCODE_B
31 --> "KEYCODE_C
32 --> "KEYCODE_D
33 --> "KEYCODE_E
34 --> "KEYCODE_F
35 --> "KEYCODE_G
36 --> "KEYCODE_H
37 --> "KEYCODE_I
38 --> "KEYCODE_J
39 --> "KEYCODE_K
40 --> "KEYCODE_L
41 --> "KEYCODE_M
42 --> "KEYCODE_N
43 --> "KEYCODE_O
44 --> "KEYCODE_P
45 --> "KEYCODE_Q
46 --> "KEYCODE_R
47 --> "KEYCODE_S
48 --> "KEYCODE_T
49 --> "KEYCODE_U
50 --> "KEYCODE_V
51 --> "KEYCODE_W
52 --> "KEYCODE_X
53 --> "KEYCODE_Y
54 --> "KEYCODE_Z
55 --> "KEYCODE_COMMA
56 --> "KEYCODE_PERIOD
57 --> "KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT
58 --> "KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT
59 --> "KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT
60 --> "KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT
61 --> "KEYCODE_TAB
62 --> "KEYCODE_SPACE
63 --> "KEYCODE_SYM
64 --> "KEYCODE_EXPLORER
65 --> "KEYCODE_ENVELOPE
66 --> "KEYCODE_ENTER
67 --> "KEYCODE_DEL
68 --> "KEYCODE_GRAVE
69 --> "KEYCODE_MINUS
70 --> "KEYCODE_EQUALS
71 --> "KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET
72 --> "KEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET
73 --> "KEYCODE_BACKSLASH
74 --> "KEYCODE_SEMICOLON
75 --> "KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE
76 --> "KEYCODE_SLASH
77 --> "KEYCODE_AT
78 --> "KEYCODE_NUM
79 --> "KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
80 --> "KEYCODE_FOCUS
81 --> "KEYCODE_PLUS
82 --> "KEYCODE_MENU
83 --> "KEYCODE_NOTIFICATION
84 --> "KEYCODE_SEARCH
85 --> "TAG_LAST_KEYCODE
```

**eg:-**

```
~ device.shell('input keyevent 20')--->device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_UP') 
~ device.shell('input keyevent 26')--->device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you trying to explain. I have investigated events that get generated via adb, but it differs for different versions of android. What I am trying to accomplish is a long press + drag events.